# How to deactivate output in Hadoop streaming?

Tags: python, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop-streaming

I am writing Python mapreduce programs on my cluster. My mapper parse the data and store them in HBase. There is no reducer, no output.

Below is the code for reference, if necessary.

```
class Mapper:
  ...
  def __init__(...)
     ...

  def start(self, file):
    generator = self.read_input(file)
    connection = happybase.Connection(Mapper.IP)
    self.table = connection.table(Mapper.table_name)
    for line in generator:
      self.parse(line)
      self.write()
      self.buffers = []
    self.table = None
    connection.close()

  def read_input(self, file):
    ...
  def parse(self, line):
    ...
  def write(self):
    # write buffers into HBase
    for cell in self.buffers:
      self.table.put(cell[0], cell[1])     <-  Into HBase yay
```

My question is: if I use this command in my cluster:

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*streaming*.jar \
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
-file /home/hduser/mapper.py    -mapper /home/hduser/mapper.py \
-input /user/hduser/streamingTest/testFile.csv
```

It will say: **oops, ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Missing required option: output**

Can I redirect the output to stdout, or deactivate it totally maybe?

PS: I am a terrible python programmer, please point out any code that makes you uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to generate some output.  Given the desire to not output *anything* use a

```
NullOutputFormat
```

as follows:

```
---outputformat org.apache.mapreduce.lib.NullOutputFormat
```

Comment: How about redirect the output to screen, is that possible? Because my mapper runs hourly, not one time. Outputting to file will generate tremendous number of files.

Comment: Hi @javadba I think after the script complete, python will automatically handle any connection, maybe? I am learning from you.

Comment: @Vindicate  That *may* be the case but it is better practice/safer to explicitly close the connection.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I think you might want to remove the specific NullOutputFormat location, it seems change from version to version.

Comment: Do you mind I modify my code to add disconnection() ? Then your answer would be two lines only, cool!

Comment: i gather you want me to remove the comment about adding disconnect() ? (done..)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74062/discussion-between-vindicate-and-javadba).